# How to set up acts_as_votable without devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987378/how-do-i-set-up-acts-as-votable-to-not-require-user-sign-in) (I'm trying to let people vote without logging in, 1 vote/ip) and when I press the upvote button I'm getting the following error:

> NoMethodError in CommentsController#upvote undefined method
>   `find_or_create_by_ip' for #
>
> Extracted source (around line #7):
>
> ```
> 5      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
> 6      session[:voting_id] = request.remote_ip
> 7      voter = Session.find_or_create_by_ip(session[:voting_id])
> 8      voter.likes @comment
> 9      flash[:message] = 'Thanks for voting!'
> 10     respond_to do |format|
> ```

I followed everything in the post, I created a Session model and added all the code to my files. Here is my code:

```
#routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts  do
    resources :comments do
      member do
        post :upvote
      end
    end
  end

  root "posts#index"
end

#models:

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  acts_as_votable
end

class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_voter
end
```

---

```
#controller:
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post

  def upvote
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    session[:voting_id] = request.remote_ip
    voter = Session.find_or_create_by_ip(session[:voting_id])
    voter.likes @comment
    flash[:message] = 'Thanks for voting!'
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def create
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    if @comment.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Comment was deleted."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Comment could not be deleted."
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end

  def comment_params
    params[:comment].permit(:content)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Session.find_or_create_by_ip(session[:voting_id])` is a [dynamic attribute finder+builder](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/guides/source/active_record_querying.md#find-or-build-a-new-object) method provided by Active Record, and it assumes that the `sessions` table has a column named `ip`.

Make sure the `sessions` table has a column named `ip`.

Also, the preferred rails 4 way of writing the same is:

```
Session.find_or_create_by(ip: session[:voting_id])
```

Comment: I added the **ip** column to the sessions table and edited the line to what you advised. I'm still getting the same error: `undefined method 'find_or_create' for #`

Comment: Typo. It should be `find_or_create_by`. You should read the link I have included. :-)

Comment: Thank you it works. Actually when I created the sessions model I assumed that voting_id should be a column in the sessions table. Should I delete that?