# acts_as_votable using ip address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, voting, voting-system

I want to allow users to vote on posts without signing up, and have the vote instead tied to their ip address. I tried following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679742/how-to-set-up-acts-as-votable-without-devise?lq=1) but I need some more clarification. this is the error im getting from the posts_controller

> undefined method `find_or_create_by_ip' for #

This is my code so far:

posts_controller:

```
def upvote 
    @post = Post.find (params[:id])
    session[:voting_id] = request.remote_ip
    upvote = session.find_or_create_by_ip(session[:voting_id])
    @post.upvote
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def downvote  
    @post = Post.find (params[:id])
    session[:voting_id] = request.remote_ip
    downvote = session.find_or_create_by_ip(session[:voting_id])
    @post.downvote
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

session model:

```
 class session < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_voter
    request.remote_ip
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'static_pages/home'
  get 'static_pages/about'
  resources :posts do
    member do 
      put "like" , to: "posts#upvote"
      put "dislike" , to: "posts#downvote"
    end
  end
```

In the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679742/how-to-set-up-acts-as-votable-without-devise?lq=1) someone said add an **ip** column to the sessions table. What exactly does that mean? I also saw somewhere that I would need to create a db table as well. do I? and how would I do that? Sorry about having to post this, put Im pretty new to this, so it would be great if it was spelled out better for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails 4+ dynamic finders have been [deprecated](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html) and extracted to a [gem](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders). The standard is now [find_or_create_by](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQ0gIoADAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapidock.com%2Frails%2Fv4.0.2%2FActiveRecord%2FRelation%2Ffirst_or_create&ei=-AqFVbaEJIq1oQSt0oCYBQ&usg=AFQjCNH25D6bsrdekWX2HUtC_UUTJiqUHQ) or  [find_or_initialize_by](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQ0gIoATAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapidock.com%2Frails%2Fv4.0.2%2FActiveRecord%2FRelation%2Ffind_or_initialize_by&ei=-AqFVbaEJIq1oQSt0oCYBQ&usg=AFQjCNHYhbWjZQ1Awzc4Oqb7tVgypuiqhw).

```
def upvote 
    @post = Post.find (params[:id])
    session[:voting_id] = request.remote_ip
    upvote = Session.find_or_create_by(ip: session[:voting_id])
    @post.upvote
    redirect_to :back
end

def downvote  
  @post = Post.find (params[:id])
  session[:voting_id] = request.remote_ip
  downvote = Session.find_or_create_by(ip: session[:voting_id])
  @post.downvote
  redirect_to :back
end 

class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voter
  request.remote_ip
end
```

Comment: thanks, I changed that. Im stilling getting an error though.              "undefined method `find_or_create_by' for #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x7f73910>"

Comment: Ok I changed that, but now I have a new error about creating a table. "undefined local variable or method `request' for Session(Table doesn't exist):Class"  how would i go about creating that?

Comment: What are you using for authentication? Do you have migration that creates the session table?

Comment: thanks for all the help, but I'm totally lost, and I don't want to waste anymore of you time.

Comment: You probably should use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) or [Active Record Session Store](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store) and add IP address to the Session table.